# Python - Function return for a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I am converting an old Matlab code into a Python script before I lose access to my Matlab license.

The purpose of the Python code is to write a script that calculates an optimal I-beam geometry given a specified force requirement and distance from the force loading point.

When the function does not return anything and just prints 'vals' (i.e. `print(vals)`), the output shows me all possible combinations which is desirable. However when I return the vals array (i.e. `return vals`), the output is just 0.0. I am not too sure why I am unable to return vals.

Ideally I want to achieve a 2D array of all possible combinations of vals (it should be a 980x980 array), then extract the maximal value of vals using a different function call.

This is my code:

```
## Defining the system inputs
sigma = 100 # Max stress not allowed to exceed (N/mm^2)
F = 100 * 10**3 # Force applied ( N)
dist = [100, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000] # Distance from force applied (mm)

t = 10 # Thickness of I-beam (mm)
y = np.zeros(1000 - 2*t) # Pre-allocating vector with zeroes
h = np.arange(1, 1001 - 2*t, 1)  # Height of I-beam
w = np.arange(1, 1001 - 2*t, 1) # width of I-beam

tol = 2.00 # tolerance for the system (how close we want our desired shear modulus to be to the limit)


# Writing the IBeam function
def IBeam(sigma, F, t, h, w, dist, tol):
    M = F * dist # calculating moment
    zShear = M / sigma # calculating shear modulus based on given conditions

    # iterating through all combinations of height and width
    for i in range(0, len(h)): # iterating through the height vector
        for j in range(0, len(w)): # iterating through the width vector
            XSA = 2*t*w[j] + t*h[i] # calculating XSA for each h/w combination   
            Ix = ((t*h[i]**3)/12) + (w[j]/12)*((2*t+h[i])**3 - h[i]**3) # calculating Ix for each h/w combination
            y = h[i]/2 + t # calculating y for each h combination 

            zInt = Ix / y # calculating zInt for each Ix/y combination

            # Check to see if our zInt < zShear since this is not ideal
            if (zInt <= zShear):
                zInt = 0
            # Check to see if our zInt >= tol * zShear since this is not ideal    
            if (zInt >= tol * zShear):
                zInt = 0
            
            # Creating the relationship between zInt and XSA
            vals = zInt / XSA 
    # return vals
    return vals

# Calling the IBeam and max function
iBeamVals = IBeam(sigma, F, t, h, w, dist[0], tol)
print(iBeamVals)
```

Apologies if this questions has been asked before or to a similar capacity beforehand.

Thanks
AJ

Comment: "When the function does not return anything and just prints 'vals' (i.e. print(vals))" If you are asking a question regarding two versions of the code, please make sure it is clear *exactly* what the *complete* code is in *each* case. But at any rate, it seems like your code explicitly iterates over the array and uses individual elements, which raises two questions: 1) What are you hoping Numpy will do for your code here? 2) How are you expecting `vals` to end up containing an array, rather than a single number - what part of your code to you think will cause that to happen?

Comment: Have you read any kind of tutorial for using Numpy? Have you heard the term *broadcasting*? Are you aware, for example, that Numpy arrays allow you to multiply the array by a numeric value, and the semantics are that it multiplies each value element-wise?

Comment: Also: what is the purpose of the `dist` list, if you are only going to use one element from it?

Comment: Whether you realize it or not, it seems like the question you *actually have* is something more like "How do I use Numpy to apply a formula to multiple combinations of input values?" There are a few different approaches to this.

Comment: Does your matlab code iterate like this?  How does it return vals for all the i,j?  J see a 'preallocate of `y`, but no indexed assignment to it.  Inside the function there's a `y=` line, but that's just a local variable asignment.  I think you need to practice python with simpler functions.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes my Matlab code follows a similar structure. It was something I wanted to preserve for the Python script.

Comment: @hpaulj The `y = ` code segment refers to the distance of the neutral axis from the reference point (which is the bottom of the beam). It is not a pre-allocation for y. The y variable will allow me to calculate a relationship between the inertia and the location of the neutral axis. This is a relationship I wish to maximize. Apologise for any confusion as I did not reference it in the comments.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel Just answering your feedback:
1) I want to use numpy to output a 2d array of 980x980 values. I want to extract the maximum value of the array (I have not provided the code for the maximum value however).
2) The dist list provides different distances with which to use as an input for the IBeam function. This is a future iteration.
3) I think your question is the most appropriate way to phrase my problem at hand.